# Android - How to add id to Toolbar back button?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

For automated testing purposes I need to add **ID** to toolbar's **BACK / MENU** button view.

I tried to add id using `getChildAt` and `setId` but the id is still not set when I check the view hierarchy. `android.R.id.home` menu id does not work in my case. I need id that is set for the view when I check the view hierarchy with **Layout inspector**. Only then the id can be used for automated UI tests.

Could you suggest a way to do this?

Comment: I'm just suggesting will help to create xml file in drawable folder inside xml file put `android:drawable="@drawable/your_icon"` and `android:id="@+id/your_id"` then using  `getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.your_xml_file);` Would that do the trick?

Comment: Could you show us exactly how you're setting the ID? It works as expected for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could add id to the toolbar back button by searching for `AppCompatImageButton` and setting the id of the first found view. It's important to do this after the setup of the actionBar.

```
private void addIdToBackButton() {
     for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof AppCompatImageButton) {
            child.setId(R.id.toolbar_back_button);
            return;
        }
     }
 }

private void setUpActionBar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Title");
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(__ -> onBackPressed());

    addIdToBackButton();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

toolbar's **BACK / MENU** button has already id `android.R.id.home`
you can use this id

to perform action on that use below code

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Backarrow pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: @MarioKutlev than create a custom toolbar and set custom image as BACK / MENU than your can assign a new id to that image

Answer (score 1):

Add this code at the bottom of your activity

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_menuname, menu);
        return true;
    }
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Ward/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case android.R.id.home:
                    finish();
                    return true;
            }
       }
```